# jquery - modal pagination. prev/next

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I have some dynamic modals that appear after a click on a div.
I want to join those modals through two prev/next arrows and let people, who click on the arrows go between the modals without having to close the current modal and open the next one.

[click here](https://www.tecmasolutions.com/clients/home-configurator-1/dimensioni.php?taglio=Trilocale&style=Exclusive) to see what I'm working on. if you click on the arrow I need to go to the next prev popup modal.

So the arrows don't work

Here's the code: [

```js
    var countModal =0;
    // Get the button that opens the modal
    $('.plan-wrapper').on('click', function() {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        console.log($(this).data('count'));
        $('#myModal_'+id).css('display', 'flex');
        countModal =  $(this).data('count');
        
    })        

    // Get the button that opens the modal     
    $('.chiudi_dimensione').on('click', function() {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        $('#myModal_'+id).hide();
    })        

    $listModal = $('.mymodal');        
    console.log($listModal);
    
    $('.freccia-indietro').on('click', function(value){  
        console.log($listModal[countModal]);
        $listModal[countModal].style.display = 'none';
        countModal = countModal -1;
        if(countModal<0){
            coutModal=$listModal.count;
        }                    
        $listModal[countModal].style.display = 'flex';
    })
    
    $('.freccia-indietro').on('click', function(value){
        countModal = countModal +1;
        if(countModal>$listModal.count){
            coutModal=0;
        }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
 <div class="plan-wrapper" data-id='<?php echo $id; ?>'>
 
 <div style="opacity:1" id="myModal_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="lightbox_wrapper_dimensione">
      <div data-id='<?php echo $id; ?>' class="chiudi_dimensione">X</div>
      <div class="freccia-indietro"></div>
      <div class="freccia-avanti"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1 no class myModal seems to be present in your html maybe you should give `class=myModal` attribute to all your modals to retrive'em via `$listModal = $('.mymodal');`

2 you have a typo `coutModal` instead of `countModal`

3 to get the length of jquery collection use `length` not `count`
 replace `$listModal.count;` with `$listModal.length;`

e facci sapere ;)